# upgrading node for electron

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, chromium

I am creating an app using electron framework but when I'm trying to use async functions it gives me an error.
Because my electron uses node version 6.5.0 but node in this version doesn't support async functions.

So I am trying to upgrade my electron's node but I don't know how to create a branch or stuff like that since https://electronjs.org/docs/development/upgrading-node is the only link I found to explain this matter but I can't understand it. Can I upgrade node in my electron framework in another way?

Comment: the link is intended for Electron developers, not for Electron users. That version of Node hasn't been in use since Electron 1.4.16. You should really upgrade your Electron version since that version isn't being supported anymore

Comment: Are you trying to use native module and receiving NODE_MODULE_VERSION error? If yes then refer to this page: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules also for async operation I would use nan library: https://github.com/nodejs/nan

Comment: You can upgrade the node version of your development machine. Just download the newer version and install it.

Comment: @UsmanAfzal Electron uses it's own node version, not the one installed on the machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I upgrade node in my electron framework in another way

No, you cannot. Electron links a specific version of node with chromium in its build time, so each version of electron have a fixed version of node.js and cannot be replaced dynamically.

Either use a higher version of the electron have higher node.js version, try to manually build electron yourself is the only way to go.